How to print SQL statements and print code snippets (stack information) that call SQL statements in Flask SQL Alchemy?
I hope to be able to monitor the execution status of all SQL statements in a piece of code in Flask SQL Alchemy. If the execution exceeds three seconds, I hope to obtain its SQL statements and stack information.
I enabled SQLAlchemy logging using logging. basicConfig (), and although I was able to print out the relevant SQL statements, I was unable to obtain the stack information for executing the statement.
My code is as follows:
def test_sql():
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy.engine").setLevel(logging.INFO)

    HOST = "127.0.0.1"
    PORT = "3306"
    DATABASE = "6023_xm"
    USERNAME = "root"
    PASSWORD = "root"

    start_time = datetime.now()
    engine = create_engine(
        "mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?charset=utf8mb4".format(USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST, PORT, DATABASE)
    )
    
    # The code I want to track
    UpdateShuJuKu.qy_sjk_update()

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

I have tried using a listener, but the code in the listener is not working:
    @event.listens_for(engine, "after_cursor_execute")
    def after_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
        from flask import current_app

        total_time = time.time() - context._query_start_time

        stack = "".join(traceback.format_stack())
        logger.info(f"===============stack information:\n{stack}")

What shall I do?

Try configuring the level on your logger: logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

@snakecharmerb Thank you for your response. After posting, I suddenly realized that setting the INFO level log information could print out how many seconds each operation took. The log information appears in the form of [generated in xxxs]. However, I still haven't tried the listener solution successfully and have given up.

The [generated in xxxs] messages refer to the amount of time take to construct the query string, not the time taken to execute the query.

@snakecharmerb After setting it to the INFO level, I can only obtain these information: [cached since xxxs ago] or [generated in xxxs]. How can I obtain this information if it is not the time when the database operation was performed?
Also, how did you know that [generated in xxxs] refers to the time taken to build a string? I couldn't find any relevant information, and even I have little knowledge about SQL algorithm's log related operations.

@snakecharmerb Recently, I have noticed that many database operations in the code take too long to execute. I obtained some query statements through MySQL's slow query logs, but I couldn't pinpoint which line of code executed the relevant operation. So I hope to use flask-sqlalchemy to print out the time and stack information of all database operations involved in a certain code segment, so that I can optimize the query logic more easily.

Details on statement compilation caching are here.  Your code works for me,  in general, but where is context._query_start_time coming from?  Also, if you are using flask-sqlalchemy (the question is tagged as flask-sqlalchemy, but the code is vanilla SQLAlchemy), have you tried using Record Queries?

MySQL also has a slow query log
